# Can anyone help me check if the translation I made is correct?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters, learning

Guy 1: Good morning, everyone. I’m News Anchor (name), and welcome to Weather Weather Lang. Today is April 6, 7AM and we’ll look at the city weather forecast. Reporter (name), how’s the weather today?

Dàjiā zǎoshanɡ hǎo. Wǒ shì xīn wén zhǔ bō (name), huān yíng lái dào “Weather Weather Lang”. Jīn tiān shì sì yuè liù hào, zǎo shàng qī diǎn. Wǒ men lái kàn chéng shì tiān qì yù bào. Jì zhě (name), jīn tiān tiān qì zěn me yàng?

Guy 2: Thank you, News Anchor (name). Good morning, everyone. Let’s now check the current weather condition of the city. Today is a sunny day and the heat is expected to last for a week. It will be a hot week because the city is currently in the summer season. But on Tuesday and Wednesday, we should expect showers to light rain at night. What’s the temperature today, Reporter (name)?

Xiè xiè, xīn wén zhǔ bō (name). Zǎo shàng hǎo, dà jiā. Xiànzài wǒmen lái kàn chéng shì de tiān qì xiàn zhuàng. Jīn tiān shì qíng tiān, xiàtiān de shǔqì yùjì jiāng chíxù yī zhōu. Jiāng huì shì yī zhōu de rè de zhōu, yīnwèi chéngshì xiànzài shì xiàtiān jìjié. Dàn xīngqī'èr hé xīngqīsān, wǒmen yīnggāi yùdào yèwǎn zhenyu zhuan xiao yu. Jīn tiān duō shǎo dù, jì zhě (name).

Guy 3: Thank you Reporter (name). The city’s current temperature is at 34 degrees Celsius. Yesterday, it went up to 37 degrees, the day after tomorrow, it will drop to 32 degrees. In this hot weather, what should we do to cool ourselves down, Reporter (name)?

Xiè xiè, Jì zhě (name). Chéng shì de xiàn zài wēn dù shì sān shí sì shèshìdù. Zuó tiān you sheng dao san shi qi du, houtian you hui jiang dao zhiyou san shi er du. Zài zhè zhǒng yánrè de tiānqì lǐ, wǒmen yīnggāi zěnme zuò lái jiàngwēn ne, jìzhě (name)?

Guy 4: The weather is really hot today, Reporter (name). That is why we invited a guest to share some tips on how to survive this weather. Let us welcome a lifestyle expert, Mr. (name). What are some ways to stay cool and stay comfortable?

Jīntiān tiānqì zhēn de hěn rè, (name) jìzhě. Zhè jiùshì wèishéme wǒmen yāoqǐng le yī wèi kèrén fēnxiǎng rúhé zài zhè zhǒng tiānqì zhōng shēngcún de jìqiǎo. Ràng wǒmen huānyíng shēnghuó fāngshì zhuānjiā (name) xiānshēng. Yǒu nǎxiē fāngfǎ kěyǐ ràng wǒmen bǎochí liángkuài shūshì ne?

Guy 5: To stay cool during hot weather, drink plenty of water, wear loose clothing, and protect your skin with sunscreen. Consider using an umbrella or a cap for shade when outside.

Zài yán rè de tiānqì zhōng bǎochí liángkuài, yào duō hē shuǐ, bìkāi gāowēn shíduàn dāi zài shìnèi, chuān tòuqì de yīfú, bìng yòng fángshài shuāng bǎohù pífū. Zài hùwài shí, kǎolǜ shǐyòng yǔsǎn huò màozi zhēyīn.

Guy 4: Thank you for joining us today and sharing your helpful tips for staying cool during hot weather. Back to you, News Anchor (name).
Gǎnxiè nín jīntiān de dàolái bìng fēnxiǎng zài yán rè tiānqì zhōng bǎochí liángkuài de yǒuyòng jìqiǎo. Huí dào nǐle, xīnwén zhǔbò (name)

Guy 1: That’s our weather report for today. Stay safe and stay informed. Thank you.

Zhè jiù shì jīntiān de tiānqì yùbào. Qǐng zhùyì ānquán bìng bǎochí guānzhù. Xièxie.

Answer (score 1):

### 前言

抱歉，我暫時不太懂得使用英語回答你的問題，但我能看懂你說的，所以我先暫時使用中文回答你的問題吧，請見諒。

我想你或者可以複製我整段的文字到另外一些翻譯軟件裏，例如說 chatgpt、Google Translator、deepl 等等，那麼你就懂得我在大致說甚麼了。

我主要作答的地區文字：中文繁體

---

### 正式回答

首先第一點，我不太明白為甚麼你要用普通話拼音來翻譯？為甚麼不直接寫成中文？

我之所以這麼問你，是因為整篇全是拼音，這讓我看得很辛苦。

加上你寫的東西太多了，這樣我會感覺可能包括我的大多數人也可能不太會有較大的意願回答你。一點愚見，願見諒。

下面是我的一些認為需要更正的地方：

---

Guy 2:

Zǎo shàng hǎo, dà jiā ->
Option 1: 大家早上好。
Option 2: 大家好。
Option 3: 早上好。

Xiànzài wǒmen lái kàn chéng shì de tiān qì xiàn zhuàng. ->
現在我們先來看看城市的天氣情況

Jīn tiān shì qíng tiān ->
今天天晴

xiàtiān de shǔqì yùjì jiāng chíxù yī zhōu ->
這個高溫情況預期會持續一整週

Jiāng huì shì yī zhōu de rè de zhōu, yīnwèi chéngshì xiànzài shì xiàtiān jìjié ->
因為正值夏季，整個星期也會很熱

Dàn xīngqī'èr hé xīngqīsān, wǒmen yīnggāi yùdào yèwǎn zhenyu zhuan xiao yu ->
但在星期二和星期三的夜晚，就預計會是陣雨到小雨

---

Guy 3:

Chéng shì de xiàn zài wēn dù shì sān shí sì shèshìdù ->
現在的城市溫度是 34 度

Zuó tiān you sheng dao san shi qi du ->
昨天升到了 37 度

houtian you hui jiang dao zhiyou san shi er du->
後天溫度則會降到 32 度

Zài zhè zhǒng yánrè de tiānqì lǐ, wǒmen yīnggāi zěnme zuò lái jiàngwēn ne ->
在這麼炎熱的天氣下，我們應該要怎麼做才能保持涼爽？

---

Guy 4:

Jīntiān tiānqì zhēn de hěn rè —>
今天是真的熱

Zhè jiùshì wèishéme wǒmen yāoqǐng le yī wèi kèrén fēnxiǎng rúhé zài zhè zhǒng tiānqì zhōng shēngcún de jìqiǎo —>
所以我們就請來了一位嘉賓來為我們說說如何能好好度過這個炎熱的天氣

Ràng wǒmen huānyíng shēnghuó fāngshì zhuānjiā (name) xiānshēng —>
option 1: 有請生活專家 name 老師
option 2: 有請生活專家 name 先生

Yǒu nǎxiē fāngfǎ kěyǐ ràng wǒmen bǎochí liángkuài shūshì ne? ->
有甚麼消暑的好方法呢？

---

Guy 5:

Zài yán rè de tiānqì zhōng bǎochí liángkuài —>
option 1: 為了保持清爽
option 2: 為了能在炎熱天氣下保持涼爽

---

Guy 4:

de yǒuyòng jìqiǎo —>
option 1: 的實用方法
option 2: 的小密招
option 3: 的方法

Zhè jiù shì jīntiān de tiānqì yùbào ->
這就是今天所有的天氣預報了

bìng bǎochí guānzhù —>
並留意最新消息

Xièxie —>
謝謝收看